# Static Id's in Tridion?

Tags: cme, content-manager

Was wondering if there are some predefined static id's in Tridion or not.
Type: "Folder" id is "2"
Type: "Structure Group" id is "4"
Type: "Categories and Keywords" id is empty?
Type: "Publication" id is  "1"
etc.

Where are these id's coming from, how to get them via core services? Or they are just static?

Thanks,
bvl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are always the same. You can find it in the CoreService or TOM.NET API docs, when checking for `ItemType Enumeration`. In case you can't find it, here they are:

None 0
 Publication 1
 Folder 2
 StructureGroup 4
 Schema 8
 Component 16
 ComponentTemplate 32
 Page 64
 PageTemplate 128
 TargetGroup 256
 Category 512
 Keyword 1024
 TemplateBuildingBlock 2048
 VirtualFolder 8192
 PublicationTarget 65537
 TargetType 65538
 TargetDestination 65540
 MultimediaType 65544
 User 65552
 Group 65568
 DirectoryService 65664
 DirectoryGroupMapping 65792
 Batch 66048
 MultipleOperations 66048    - Obsolete
 PublishTransaction 66560
 WorkflowType 67584
 ApprovalStatus 131073
 ProcessDefinition 131074
 ProcessInstance 131076
 ProcessHistory 131080
 ActivityDefinition 131088
 ActivityInstance 131104
 ActivityHistory 131136
 WorkItem 131200

Comment: thanks! the same id numbers are valid for Tridion 2013 as well? for example Page has "id" or number 64 in Tridion 2011 and 2013 too? bvl

Comment: Yes, ItemTypes are always the same

Comment: A few things might break if they changed. :-) They're arrangement makes it easier to combine multiple types with a single number (as a sum). Bart Koopman uses this approach with the [Item Selector Custom URL Extension][http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx].

Answer (score 10):

The examples you listed are for item *types*, not IDs.

In general, IDs will be determined by the database - whereas item types will be static as you say.

A TCM URI consists of anywhere from 2 to 4 parts separated by a dash (listed in order):

- The ID of the Publication it belongs to. This is 0 if the item is not in a Publication (e.g. Users, Groups, Publication Targets, etc.)
- The ID of the item itself. This is typically an auto-increasing number.
- The item type of the item (Folder, Component, etc.) The possible values for this are fixed and will be the same for all items of that type. You can view the full list of item types by looking at the API documention for the ItemType enumeration (although add-on products occasionally introduce new ones that are not covered there). Components are the most common item type in the system and so typically do not include their item type (16) in the URI (but it's not a problem to do so).
- (Optional) The version of the item in question. Version 0 is the currently edited / checked out version and anything else refers to a specific version of the item. If this part is left out (most of the time), the URI is version-agnostic and the latest version is implied.

"Categories and Keywords" (as well as a few other entries in the CME) is not a real item -- it is only used for grouping entries within the Content Manager Explorer. Such entries will they have a non-standard URI (but they still have one for reference, navigation, etc.).

Here are the list of Content Manager item types as of Tridion 2013:

```
Publication = 1
Folder = 2
StructureGroup = 4
Schema = 8
Component = 16
ComponentTemplate = 32
Page = 64
PageTemplate = 128
TargetGroup = 256
Category = 512
Keyword = 1024
TemplateBuildingBlock = 2048
VirtualFolder = 8192
PublicationTarget = 65537
TargetType = 65538
TargetDestination = 65540
MultimediaType = 65544
User = 65552
Group = 65568
DirectoryService = 65664
DirectoryGroupMapping = 65792
MultipleOperations = 66048
MultipleOperations = 66048
PublishTransaction = 66560
WorkflowType = 67584
ApprovalStatus = 131073
ProcessDefinition = 131074
ProcessInstance = 131076
ProcessHistory = 131080
ActivityDefinition = 131088
ActivityInstance = 131104
ActivityHistory = 131136
WorkItem = 131200
```

Answer (score 8):

What you have mentioned are item type ids. Last part of TCM URI of an item has item type id.

For example, in tcm:493-20830-2, '2' is the item type id and the item in context is a folder.

'16' is the item type id for Components. However item type id in Component TCM URI is optional.